# What are the implications of private keyword in java?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jvm, private-members, object-oriented-analysis

The following code works & runs perfectly.

```
public class Complex {

private int real, imag;

Complex(int r, int i) {
    real = r;
    imag = i;
}

public static Complex add(Complex c1, Complex c2) {
    return new Complex(c1.real + c2.real, c1.imag + c2.imag);
}

public String toString() {
    return real + "+i" + imag;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer.parseInt("5");
    System.out.println(Complex.add(new Complex(2, 3), new Complex(3, 4)));

}

}
```

Now according to Object oriented design model, private instance members shouldn't be accessed through a object reference (which has been done here by c1.real ).

So, in that sense,there should be compiler error. But it doesn't object.

Now according to my understanding it's allowed because

1. c1.real code is written in the body of the private class Complex class itself.
2. Developer of Complex class should have access to all instance members [be it private,protected  whatever] when accessing through an object reference, since Developer knows very well what he's doing unlike any third party. That's why object oriented model model isn't followed here.

Can anyone suggest a better explanation about why c1.real code is allowed here?

Comment: "private instance members can't be accessed through a object reference" - where does that come from?

Comment: The idea of private/protected is to hide the innards from the outside world.  There's nothing wrong with a class knowing about its self.  It is, after all, the same class.

Comment: Where does this misconception come from?  => 'Object oriented design model, private instance members can't be accessed through a object reference'

Comment: +1 for a well phrased question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that because that's the way Java defined the `private` access modifier.

The longer answer is that they probably assumed that strict encapsulation only makes sense above source file level, so even an inner class can access private members of its outer class (and vice versa): it simply makes no sense to hide members within the same source file. If you've got access to the source file of a class, you can easily modify any access modifiers anyway.

(Although the inner-outer class thing is achieved via synthetic accessors, but they're almost completely transparent.)

Answer (score 4):

private means it cannot be access from another outer class. It is class based, not object based security.  Note: classes in the same outer class can access private member of any other class in that file.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/outer-class-local-access.html

Comment: package p;

public class PTest{

   PTest(){

   int b=new V().testMe;   //not allowed though defined in same file.

   }

}


class V{
  
   private int testMe=5;

}

Comment: That's not entirely true. It should read "inner classes defined in an outer class can access private members of any other class defined in the outer class." Two outer classes declared in the same file cannot access each other's private members.

Comment: @Dunes Yes.That's true.But I'm not moving into inner class discussion.Actually Peter said that "Note: classes in the same file can access private member of any other class in that file.". But that can't happen.Right?

Comment: Yeah Peter you have to specify that a bit. Interestingly enough inner classes can not only access private members of the outer class (well known) but also private members of other inner classes. So basically anything between the opening and closing braces of the class definition can access private members. Doesn't sound snappy, but I think is correct :)